# Failed prop type: ProductDetail: prop type `dataQuality` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from React.PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting the error in the title when I use

```
import {PropTypes} from 'react';

export const dataQualityShape = PropTypes.shape({
    isPending: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    issues: PropTypes.objectOf(
        PropTypes.arrayOf(
            PropTypes.shape({
                Severity: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                Message: PropTypes.string.isRequired
            }).isRequired
        ).isRequired
    ).isRequired
});
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried chaining `.isRequired` only to the outer `PropTypes.objectOf`?

Comment: @maxhallinan I tried getting rid of all the `isRequired`s and got the same error :(